# how to check for an item in dynamodb using java?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

Hi I'm trying to create a java program which checks for a value present in the amazon dynamodb.
Well actually im trying to write a java program for a retail store where the program checks for a certain product(value) in the dynamodb and returns the quantity present in the store.I already created a table in dynamodb and also used the scan api to retrieve items.But now i want to search for a certain value is present or not and also return the quantity present.
It would be really helpful if anyone could help me with a snippet.
ps: i'm new to java

Thanks

Comment: you may want to post your table schema as well?

Comment: nope just want to check for a value and return the quantity present.....

Comment: see the example in answer i wrote. you may want to project `value` only.

Answer (score 0):

Given following data modelling for a table `ConsumerTable`, with `leaseKey` as indexed field;

```
{
  "checkpoint": "49572533067729099438069946639296561054199125138133221378",
  "checkpointSubSequenceNumber": 0,
  "leaseCounter": 1372794,
  "leaseKey": "shardId-000000000000",
  "leaseOwner": "pout_172.21.63.243",
  "ownerSwitchesSinceCheckpoint": 0
}
```

Java API to query Amazon DynamoDB by the indexed field would be

```
import com.amazonaws.ClientConfiguration;

import com.amazonaws.regions.Region;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.retry.v2.RetryPolicy;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDB;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient;
import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;

public AmazonDynamoDB getDbConnection() {
    AmazonDynamoDBClient dynamoDB = new AmazonDynamoDBClient( new ProfileCredentialsProvider("your-aws-auth-profile_in_~/.aws/credentials"));

    dynamoDB.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2))

    return dynamoDB;
}

public void getData() {

    DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(getDbConnection());
    Table consumerOffsetTable = dynamoDB.getTable("ConsumerTable");

    Optional.ofNullable(consumerOffsetTable.getItem("leaseKey", "shardId-000000000000")).ifPresent(item -> {

        Map<String, Object> itemMap = item.asMap();

        System.out.println(itemMap.get("leaseKey").toString() + " -> " + itemMap.get("checkpoint").toString());

    });

}
```

Maven dependency would be

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
  <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
  <version>1.11.115</version>
</dependency>
```

In your `product`, `quantity` example, index `product` attribute and query should be similar to above example.

### Resources

For AWS access using SDK - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html

For Dynamodb apis

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/ScanJavaDocumentAPI.html

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/QueryingJavaDocumentAPI.html

Comment: hi prayag thanks for responding but im getting an error at the getTable() method.(The method getTable(String) is undefined for the type Object).Eclipse suggests to add cast to it but it doesn't resolve this issue.Facing this problem since long back

Comment: Maybe because `import com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.document.DynamoDB;` is not in import. Can you please add that?

Comment: done that!!facing this issue since long back.Eclipse suggests all the methods such as geItems() etc..But  doesn't show the getTable() method.

Comment: that can happen when `DynamoDB` instance is not initialized properly. Is the line `DynamoDB dynamoDB = new DynamoDB(getDbConnection());` green or red?

Comment: Hi prayag im sorry i didnt be more clear with you...I'm deploying this program using the aws lambda for it to run on my alexa and for that i guess i dont need the **getDBConnection()** method....

Comment: I guess You would still need connection from AWS to dynamo, but use `new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain()` instead of `new ProfileCredentialsProvider(...)`. - Read http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/credentials.html